# Не могу интегрировать gitbash c github

Tags: git, github, git-push

Недавно начал осваивать гит и возникла сразу такая проблема:
Если написать "git remote add origin git@github.com:Логин/Название_проекта.git", то выдает
"fatal: remote origin already exists."
А если написать уже "git push -u origin main", то
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В общем, попробовал удалить всю папку и инициализировать снова, но теперь стало выдавать ошибку и на этапе: git branch -M main error: refname refs/heads/master not found
fatal: Branch rename failed

Comment: Как понял позже, все настройки для гит сбились, поэтому помогло следующее:
1. git init
2. git config --global user.name ‘your name here’
3. git config --global user.email ‘your email here’
4. git add .
5. git commit -m ‘some message’
6. create new repository in github and copy ssh link
7. git remote add origin ‘ssh link copied above’
8. git push -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать добавить по HTTPS удаленный репозиторий в GitHub:

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`, где ваш логин - это `USERNAME`, `REPOSITORY` - название вашего проекта.

Comment: Оно выдает тоже самое: fatal: remote origin already exists.

Comment: какой вывод после `git remote -v`?

Comment: хм. http? вроде же от него с доступом по паролю отказались?

Comment: @KoVadim а вы попробуйте, сегодня пользовался )

Comment: NAME    URL (fetch)
NAME    URL (push)
origin  git@github.com:Логин/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Логин/repo.git (push)

Comment: @Евгений попробуйте заменить ссылку `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Comment: @highpassion, я уже написал, что выдает абсолютно тоже самое

Comment: попробуйте `git push origin main` без -u

Comment: @highpassion, error: src refspec main does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Comment: запустите `git commit -m "commit"` и пробуйте пуш `git push origin main`

Comment: @Евгений смотрите, чтобы в выводе `git show-ref` было `refs/heads/main` и `refs/remotes/origin/main`

Comment: @highpassion, после удаления корневой папки мне пришлось делать повторную инициализации и заново вводить конфиги, также добавив коммит и только после этого все нормально заработало!

Comment: @Евгений очень хорошо ) я тоже так делаю, когда ловлю ступор, но стоит понимать, что если разобраться пошагово, то можно научится понимать как работает система

Comment: @highpassion, благодарю вас за помощь